# regex for url rewrite but keep the source url in the address bar

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite a url.

Source: domain/event-detail/sport/event/?event=171990

Target: domain/event-detail/?event=171990

but the Source URL should be displayed in the address bar.

I thought of something like:

```
if url contains "event-details" and /*/*/?event=XX (/event-details/*/*) -> /event-detail/?event=XX
```

And then a rewrite rule to display the source url. How to do it?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: by `*` you mean any character except `/` 1 time or more which is written in regex `[^/]+`

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/event-detail/.+/.+/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^event=\d+$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/event-detail/? [R=301,L]
```

Following your logic, capture URIs containing `event-detail/.+/.+/` and having a query parameter like `event=\d+`

Comment: `%{REQUEST_URI}` means `URL path` ie `/event-detail` domain name is not part of the `REQUEST_URI` variable.